# Error al insertar multiples registros con Django Rest framework

Tags: python, django

Hola envio esto desde VUe.js
[image: peticion]

y intento por cada registro de la lista de ASSETS realizar un insert en una tabla de relacion asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me devuelve un error:
ValueError: Cannot assign xxxx "FieldAdjunto.field" must be a "ReportResponseSectionField" instance.

Comment: Sugiero que en lugar de usar Vue.js uses Javascript puro. Y en lugar de Django uses Python. Asi tendrás más control en lo que haces.

Comment: Pon el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.